# SQL Server sp_create_plan_guide and LIKE clause parameter

Tags: sql-server, parameters, sql-like, sql-execution-plan

I am having trouble dealing with LIKE clause when i am creating plan guides. Real query i had trouble with was enormous so i made up tiny one just to describe my issue. Here is summary of my trouble:

Query i am trying to create plan for is:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Company WHERE Addres LIKE '%somestring%' AND Site = 'whateversite'
```

So i have ran sp_get_query_template to get query template, it looked like this:

```
DECLARE @my_templatetext nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @my_parameters nvarchar(max)
EXEC sp_get_query_template
@templatetext = N'SELECT ID, Name FROM Company WHERE Addres
LIKE ''%somestring%'' AND Site = ''whateversite''',
@templatetext = @my_templatetext OUTPUT,
@parameters = @my_parameters OUTPUT
SELECT @my_templatetext
SELECT @my_parameters
```

Return is:

Parametrized query:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Company WHERE Addres LIKE '%somestring%' AND Site = @0
```

And Parameters:

```
@0 nvarchar(4000)
```

Then i will finally run sp_create_plan_guide procedure, which looks like this:

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide
@name = N'TSY_PLAN2',
@stmt = N'SELECT ID, Name FROM Company WHERE Addres LIKE ''%somestring%''
AND Site = @0',
@type = N'SQL',
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = N'@0 nvarchar(4000)'
```

When i run query i posted in first block, it works perfectly! But when i submit different Address then '%Somestring%', it wont work. It is for sure because of LIKE ''%somestring%'' part of the query template... But i cannot figure out how to make it work with parameter in LIKE clausule.

I tryed creating plan for query with parameter for LIKE clausule, it looked like this:

```
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide
@name = N'TSY_PLAN2',
@stmt = N'SELECT ID, Name FROM Company WHERE Addres LIKE @1like
AND Site = @0',
@type = N'SQL',
@module_or_batch = NULL,
@params = N'@1like nvarchar(4000),@0 nvarchar(4000)'
```

but it wont work at all... i even used many combinations of percents, comas and paragraphs but no luck at all.

After many desperate trials and failures i found out via actual execution plan function, that optimizer does not see LIKE "parameter" as parameter at all... it sees the real '%somestring%' value. Optimiser sees query as:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Company WHERE Addres LIKE '%somestring%'
AND Site = @0'
```

If i fill different '%somestring%' i would need different plan guide? That would kinda make plan guides useless as '%somestring%' changes frequently. I refuse to believe it is not possible! I need my optimiser to use hash joins every time not for particular string in LIKE clause...

In the end in real life i deled with the issue by fiddling arround with the indexes... but it took a lot of time! As a fast work arround i wanted to do plan guide.

Can you please help me how to create plan guide for "parameter" in LIKE clause? Is it even possible? Do i need to set my database somehow to "parametrize LIKE clausules"?